# Is there an easier way to fuse materials from your inventory to a melee weapon?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

When shooting an arrow, there's a single-button prompt to fuse a material from your inventory to the arrow.  However, so far, the only way I've found to fuse a material (monster horn, etc) to your melee weapon, is to go into the inventory, hold the item, drop the item, then select the fuse power.

I feel like there should be a prompt from the fuse power to select a material, but I don't see it listed in the controls at the bottom of the screen.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you press Direction Pad <kbd>↑</kbd> when *not* using a bow, you'll pull up the same material quick-menu. Once here, simply find the appropriate item (sorting by "Fuse Attack Power" might help), and press <kbd>X</kbd> to drop it at your feet. Once done, you'll have the item on the ground in front of you, ready to be Fused, no <kbd>+</kbd> menu required!

Do note you'll need enough space around Link's feet, so if you get a message about "can't do that here", simply back up to clear some room and try again.

Comment: I suspect the first time I tried this, I got the "can't do that here" message, and assumed I was doing something wrong, as opposed to the problem being I was standing somewhere crowded. I'll give this a try tonight

Comment: Although this isn't quite as easy as with the bow, I suspect being able to fuse with the weapon or shield is what makes this implementation a little clunkier.  For future readers, it doesn't take much to get the "cant' do that" message.  Even a slope going the wrong direction can cause the error.  Make sure you're on flat, clear ground.